# Getting different results for setTimeout & setImmediate inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
setImmediate(function () {
    console.log('setImmediate')
});

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('setTimeout')
}, 0);
```

outputs

```
setTimeout
setImmediate
```

But, these two functions inside setTimeout outputs different results.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    setImmediate(function () {
        console.log('setImmediate')
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('setTimeout')
    }, 0);
}, 0);
```

Output:

```
setImmediate
setTimeout
```

Comment: Just ignore [`setImmediate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate): _"This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future."_

Comment: But there must be some logic to the flow of their execution, right? They both lie in the event loop's order of operations.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834122/how-is-timing-of-setimmediate-and-settimeout-bound-by-the-performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know the event loop looks like this-

```
timers -> IO -> poll -> check ->close -> timers -> ...
```

Timers: callbacks from setInterval or setTimeout
IO callbacks: callbacks from I/O events
Idle: used internally by Node between IO and Poll phases
Poll: retrieve new I/O events
Check: callbacks from setImmediate execute here
Close: handle closed connections like sockets

In the first Example -

We can see setTimeout gets executed before the setImmediate because **timer queue** is placed before the **check Queue**.

However in the second case -

When the setTimeout gets executed it triggers another setTimeout and a setImmediate, Since the **Check queue** is placed after the **timer queue**, the Check queue of the same loop executes the setImmediate but **the nested setTimeout gets scheduled for the next cycle**.

Which is why the code below is can also be used to run something regularly

```
let timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
  alert('tick');
  timerId = setTimeout(tick, 2000); // (*)
}, 2000);
```

It schedules the next call, right at the end of the first call, which basically registers the call of setTimeout for the next loop.